# Как найти точки пересечения лучей с погрешностью

Tags: математика, геометрия

Есть несколько (конкретно 6) лучей в пространстве. Не имеет значения как они заданы (я подгоню входные данные под решение, если нужно). Нужно найти точки, в которых пересекаются 3 луча за раз с заданной погрешностью (то есть 3 луча за раз скорее всего не пересекутся, но будут близки к этому).

Comment: данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что он не соответствует тематике сайта

Comment: @alexanderbarakin ну вот зачем закрывать такой интересный вопрос ?? задача же ведь как минимум имеет практическое применение в графике

Comment: @ampawd, с предложениями о расширении тематики сайта стоит обращаться на [meta].

Comment: @alexanderbarakin таких вопросов появлялось предостаточно, поэтому здесь нечего расширять - они уже являются частью тематики сайта

Comment: @ampawd, *таких вопросов появлялось предостаточно* — [да, я в курсе](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3038/178576). но это никак не влияет (в сторону расширения) на тематику сайта.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin я это к тому, что это абсолютная норма, так как многие разделы из программирования тесно пересекаются с математикой

Comment: @ampawd, ещё раз настоятельно рекомендую вам излагать аргументы не мне, а уточнить мнение сообщества на [meta]

Answer (score 3):

Найдите все попарные пересечения для каждой возможной пары лучей, а потом посмотрите, какие из этих точек отстоят друг от друга не более чем на величину погрешности.

При этом самый простой вариант такой:

Сначала отсортируйте все найденные пересечения по одной из координат (любой из двух). Далее вы перебираете эти точки от минимальной до максимальной. Вам нужно найти идущие подряд три точки, для которых разницы по этой координате не более, чем погрешность. Когда вы нашли такую тройку точек, вы уже вычисляете реальные расстояния между ними, чтобы окончательно убедиться, что это те самые три точки.

А дальше уже либо работаете с этой тройкой точек, либо вычисляете некую среднюю точку.

Comment: Тут не совсем ясно с погрешностью. Я не пояснил что такое погрешность, потому что сам не до конца понимаю. Расстояние между точек не канает, потому что при очень небольшом расстоянии между точкой и противоположной стороной, длина этой стороны может быть чуточку больше.  Максимальный радиус вписанной в треугольник окружности не подходит, потому что в треугольнике с тупым углом с этим все печально. Возможно, надо измерять биссектрисы... но не факт.

Comment: @iRumba, просто вычислите для тройки точек длины всех трёх образованных ими отрезков, и проверьте, что все три длины меньше допустимой погрешности.